# April Fools' Day Hoax: Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I read [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/235014/76903) to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/235008/76903) on MathOverflow, and I enjoyed reading the proof given in [the linked paper](http://www.princeton.edu/~aloo/fermat), but... where is the mistake? I know nothing of the Mason-Stothers Theorem except its statement and truth, and the reasoning in the paper seems to be logically sound to me.

Intuitively, I feel that the result obtained (that there cannot exist *complex polynomials* with the given conditions) does not actually imply the statement of Fermat's Last Theorem (which deals with *positive integers*), though I cannot justify this. Could anyone explain the flaw in the proof?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a dumb trick; the author's just misstating the Mason-Stothers theorem, which includes the condition that the three polynomials are relatively prime. Here the polynomials are all multiples of $t$ so they aren't relatively prime.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, the third example on the Mason-Stothers Theorem's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Stothers_theorem) is still true for relatively prime polynomials, right?

Comment: @shardulc: yes, but it just doesn't imply FLT over the integers.